# Conditional React component properties with multiple generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I am trying to implement a `Typography` component in React, and need to make it flexible enough, so it will as:

1. `variant` prop is mandatory
2. the `as` prop is optional

   a. if `as` is a string, it will be a native html tag and surface this tag's properties

   b. if `as` is a react element, it will surface the react element's properties

   c. if `as` is not defined, it will default to the variant's mapped element

For example if `as="a"`, we expect that `href` property will exist.

The example code is below, which works when testing the type `Proxy` only but using it with the react component it is not working:

```
import React from "react";

const TypographyDefaultMapping = {
    h1: 'h1',
    h2: 'h2',
    h3: 'h3',
    'body-medium': 'span',
    label: 'span',
} as const;

export type TypographyVariants = keyof typeof TypographyDefaultMapping;

type Tags = keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap;

type AsType = undefined | Tags | React.FunctionComponent<any>;

type VariantsDefaultType<T extends TypographyVariants> = Omit<
    React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof TypographyDefaultMapping[T]>,
    'as'
> & {
    variant: TypographyVariants;
};

export type NewConditionalTypography<
    T extends AsType,
    V extends TypographyVariants
> = T extends undefined
    ? VariantsDefaultType<V> // Undefined "as" property, fallback to variant's default
    : T extends Tags
    ? {
        variant: TypographyVariants;
        as: Tags;
        bloup: boolean;
    } & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T> // "as" property is a valid HTML tag
    : T extends React.FunctionComponent<any> // "as" property is a React element
    ? {
        variant: TypographyVariants;
        as: React.FunctionComponent<any>;
        bib: boolean;
    } & React.ComponentProps<T>
    : never;

type Proxy<T = unknown> = T extends {
    as: infer As extends AsType;
    variant: infer Var extends TypographyVariants;
}
    ? NewConditionalTypography<As, Var>
    : T extends {
        variant: infer Var extends TypographyVariants; // case of not defined "as"
    }
    ? NewConditionalTypography<undefined, Var> 
    : never;

const NewTypography = (props: Proxy) => (
    <div>Test: {JSON.stringify(props)}</div>
);

const Link = ({ linkClick }: { linkClick: () => void }) => (
    <button onClick={linkClick}>Test</button>
);

// Expected to get HTMLHeadingElement props + variant prop
type TestProxy = Proxy<{ variant: 'h2' }>;
     // ^?

// Expected to get HTMLSpanElement props + variant prop
type TestProxySpan = Proxy<{ variant: 'body-medium' }>;
     // ^?

// Expected to get HTMLAnchor props + variant prop
type TestProxy2 = Proxy<{ variant: 'h2'; as: 'a' }>;
     // ^?

// Expected to get Link element props + variant prop
type TestProxy3 = Proxy<{ variant: 'h2'; as: typeof Link }>;
     // ^?

const TestingComponent = () => (
    <div>
    // Should allow (and auto-complete) "href"
        <NewTypography variant="h2" />
    // Should allow (and auto-complete) "linkClick"
        <NewTypography
            variant="body-medium"
            as={Link}
        //   linkClick={() => console.log('Test')}
        />
    // Should not allow "href"
        <NewTypography variant="body-medium" as="span" href="www.example.com" />
    </div>
);
```

or as a [Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#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-t4RQB%20Ik1jpGylVTGNbkAehHcAAqj8-ujvARsvg4GB5UhYMxjHAhKJRB50F0KhA4J6SRd9DlWxSYCLfSWy4yQesu273O5j97fZX-eygyL3NlfaCFAvhoHiiGqYB6F4ECnNEQEaJkroQhgUISmi0pyhACrKjAqrqpq1KjuO%20ALkuK5rnAwA5CgR4psAc57IcFRrNeNS3k2SHQnCNAIsiqJSliOKEfOdCLsumGrpUFFUaKkK0qc5xXu43aqMB6hvu0H51Om36cnBwH-jJyFcTxNCofxQqCXpL4eMAHiQRA0GoDQVkIYZ4p8eiFwYQqBEsei7qrgS1QYcUGY0l8NBdDQEAxjQ3JKA2d45CpGgGbImCrq8OQ5uWWUfFZ6kXHo6WZcSbG5WmDQ6R0wZPtGca0MEMBJimlW8JibwbsSuIsYlTYpcBhU%20hRNAZVAPbjTl95tQGJ41XAY65Nk1TDNF8Ctu2wn4CK6R1bG8ZNS1qafummItjOQRdS03J%20UgAVQIUeQMFGsYzTyAAUYkKnoIXMAAlIo3LvSKmLBO6uKMEgDB6MoABSADKvLXFCDCtHIwCYMwn3ynQf3pJiI5gz1f2PbQz0HLI%205KO9yhwKIlNIvTaD7ukMN0wzTNdHo70Awo3LuhAdFwOkvNAyDHjqjAtBwMinMKMo9ORYzwDM%20kENQ0KI4SzAUtxeQJOUItRylEgGAAlLcBsEg8AMQcOyoMEcgnGc0qkZhOQANQ0XNbtgOQkaQwwv08r9mK00NLi2ML%20K-otAB6naG%20OxvLGbc4W1bNv7Ac8OpM7Cm%20573ver7-vPIHso4KFufRCHVcZuHvbWF4vgBEEIRhNHVkLeOCdJ3AKem-S6eHpncC2y83GquNX1F0NpcBxrv0WHXEChWHxcaQYlj6KQWR0NYKD6F3se94n5BGybacHpb1twBTkVyS7FyF3AXvz19ZeEhXv2OKv6%20NzmpHXe%2089A6mGA-FmMcXzx3Pk9JgGt5hmU8vAamos4DA3cKDYA4MRSLXhrhUQc4UxgRjBg6IxD1QQD8NQcApx6QA3wNwIgmBtqqTgJieqb0hoKCYRYRcI4eruHwYQ4h24YrkJ%20FkKhNDUT0KQIwxWXRlbMzYapThr0ToNF-KpHh%20AW7%20ECMEUIaj2HqGyPLSBu12GLXUEolRXR5Y80BrkMmjkoRgTYO9fQFd9B4x0eoQReDxwELVEQuAa0sjiLIUwlhpiXwaJjNw3svCDFt2MSARcFj8CRGiIuZhgheHZG8MUgRQiNAEyJvrCgQA).

Any clue how can achieve this, and if it's feasible after all?

[Edit]:

1. Simplified playground [based on comments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#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-t4RQB%20Ik1jpGylVTGNbkAehHcAAqj8-ujvARsvg4GB5UhYMxjHAhKJRB50F0KhA4J6SRd9DlWxSYCLfSWy4zRZDYfCYEmJWjpdiaHi4GP53RF8uEDLGucDADkKAPhgtKnOcV7uN2qjuO4x7er6lb%20uyQZZHQegQhgT40AiyKolKWI4viIqZK6eHiiR6IXHKQF0NSuLXnA6LuquBLVIxxQZow3JKA2d45IhGjZHosiYKurw5Dm5ayR8FDIb2kk0NJUA9pp8n3mmDSYZywZdlGsbxsEL60Cmem8JibwbsSrHuDeOmiSKKknj6oHqTJxK3k21kBh5dCkD%2045oNk1TDDQEDwK27Z-vglHGdGca0OZSZWeh6aYi2M5BPZLSORoegcVxlB5AwJkxgFPLUn5CnkQAFIBCp6Lx-G4gAlIo3KNSKmLBO6uKMEgDB6MoABSADKvLXFCDCtHIwCYMwzXynQnXpJiI6DaxnWFBV8AHLI%205KI1yhwKIJ1IldaD7uk42Xddt1dHojXdQo3LuhAwBzukH29f1HjqjAtBwMiL0KMoV00F0N3AHd6TDaNQojsDMCgzQe2FL%20RylEgGAAqDcBsEg8B7IcOyoMEcgnGc0pLutcAANRHr2jNAeQkYjQwbxTnFs48u1mIXSh7QuLYcBI8p7i-gAep2lC4-jhNzsTpNHSd0H0xcHMKizbMeXrXPPDzMBvDRb6kfASjC6LqkGJY%20ghRJgzLMMx2w1LFFIfLitULQlVm-MVv0TbcDvT1Ef9btIq-lNqpiHOKaiBAMYR9EyfqhAfjUOApz0t1%20DcEQmCJUhGiYilNVixcCjFxYi4jkV6jx4nojJ9uacZz8WTZ7nqIF0gRcw3DL3lxXcBV7GAVuZPtcwPXXi%20AEQQhCAE%20T%20JdBQ57XTpHPrfjuoo-w3dUOR59uSBxApxQqnbCNfoZv6Jth8-i3U87cAQ3kPt5BAA)

Comment: You need to add a generic to `NewTypography`, like here `const NewTypography = <T,>(props: Proxy<T>)`. However it is not a full solution. I believe that you need to create a discriminated union type or to overload react component.

Comment: See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) for discriminated unions and [my article](https://catchts.com/react-props#second) for component overloading. Currently it is hard to understand all your requirements in conditional types. Could you please reduce it? Make minimum reproducible example , for instance with only two props ?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine a simplified playground is added to the original post (edited), where we basically would have two cases, `as=undefined` and `as=ReactElement`. Will definitely ready the article you pasted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the type parameters to the function so they can be inferred. After that some minor tweaks to  `NewConditionalTypography` and it should work:

```
export type NewConditionalTypography<
    T extends AsType,
    V extends TypographyVariants
> = // Undefined "as" property, fallback to variant's default
    T extends undefined? VariantsDefaultType<V>: 
    // "as" property is a React element
    T extends (p: any) => JSX.Element ? { bib: boolean; } & React.ComponentProps<T>: 
    // "as" property is a valid HTML tag
    T extends Tags ? { bloup: boolean; } & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T> :
    {}

const NewTypography = <TVar extends TypographyVariants, TAs extends AsType = undefined>(props: {
    as?: TAs;
    variant: TVar;
} & NewConditionalTypography<TAs, TVar> ) => (
    <div>Test: {JSON.stringify(props)}</div>
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#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-7kjHpm6PV67iKxW3rED3S9PVKfaiKwHQUHId3amEwnAAKpSmXGoz4W74OBgDNIWDJDpwIoCAR2dB2BcXQTwhFo7mlbFSmGZdd1XOBJUg2UDAAfhtUDgyrZ1vhsIFNFkYZLwIZ9X3fT84GAO4UEQYh4FOFkUxgnc929HgwFkc1TG0AApABlAANDUmQYtk4DQ-g7GAOxZDmCBmT2UhjDgAAyGj1QTJNjTZdMIEzV18LgQiryfOgXzfXSPy+CiqJAoQjFpelPlJJiV33JUyTEuQ4DsAR83Y7yIDk1AaEU65VLjTVE3AZNtIzbNc3zGBC30uBpGGXhJEoB54GHEc5wxZJaldW1mPg-LAUDe1v0CEVSrc9dBQlO9MGQzRuHMzNZF4YZbhQ2QaroChph0DCYH620KDCodR3HNYYCnGdytyV0RWq21tC4nhhhsNYdCCEIxrkPiw05DUGDBOtgEwZJ2ritRJHCXaYjiSgstoBhfgO6ooqNFNanULQtumHbgD24ZpiI3i8xKIwZ18kceD2WGnAgRZqHAZlPQ0fBsiITB8HB6wbFypbCpGu02Q4HHehfKwwhiaZgZJw950JxmQIpmAqbmBZllWdYQAJ9n2duLxmDYTLhcZyS7C8GAoAcJBJalw5hA8VgvABsx7neoKNV8tJuBaYIGBae62bgemjLgKH8wEIwaAgeA4YgBGcbxoXheJ0dSY509ufmJYVjWDYX1F-Adj2F9ccKKmXyt4Gwie2IKCAA)

Comment: This looks so elegant, not overcomplicated and to the point 

Comment: Just curious there is not any provided type from React to handle this part `p: any) => JSX.Element` ?

Comment: @konsalex I didn't get a chance to investigate but using `React.FunctionComponent<any>` does not actually work. It makes `NewConditionalTypography` `any`